# Count a dinamic text inside a string in php

Tags: php

Hi i need to count how many times a string with a progressive number, is present inside a string in PHP.

For a static text I use this:

```
$text = "foo bar foo other text inside string";
$count= substr_count($text, "foo");
echo $count; // output: 2
```

But i need to count how many time a string with a final progressive number is present. for example:

```
$text = "This is a string with some tags: tag1, tag2 and finally tag3";
```

How to find how many times tagX appear? where X is a progressive digit.
So in this case 3 times.... and **tags** need to be excluded

Comment: You're looking for regular expressions. Research how to match text with a number at the end and count the matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all occurrences of the word "tag" concatenated to numbers you can use:

```
$matches = array();

echo preg_match_all("/tag([0-9]+)/", $text, $matches);
```

$matches is a multi-dimensional array of all matches.

Comment: `preg_match_all()` returns the number of matches. No need to use `$matches` in this case. Also, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: @nachospiu first version worked. the last modified one, not. i need $matches[0]

Comment: ok, the count of occurences is return by preg_match_all() and $matches have all occurrences found.